# git push didn't push all files to repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push my project to my github repository.After I pushed the files,there is one directory unclickable on the github.Then I cloned the project and found out that the files under the directory hadn't been pushed to the repository at all.
I use the command below:

```
git init
git remote add origin <my project repo's link>
git add .
git commit -m "First initialize"
git push origin master
```

My repo's link:https://github.com/Honesty1997/root-project

I don't add .gitignore or something like this.

Comment: Is the folder you are talking about a symlink?

Comment: It's a submodule or similar. Symlink perhaps? The folder in the tree object has mode 160000 which indicates it might be its own submodule, but there is no information in your repository where this submodule should come from, thus it is empty. I have little experience with these things so my information here may be wrong but at least your file has mode 160000.

Comment: You really shouldn't commit virtual environments to source control.

Comment: Be aware that git doesn't push **files**. It push **commits**. If you feel that git should've included that blog folder then you need to figure out why `git add` didn't add it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes,it is a submodule.I just search the information.I don't even know this before.Thanks!

Comment: Would you add the error message what you got when you push the repo to origin?